# We have a problem with the CPU utilization going up to 380 % on a 4 core machine

Tags: cpu-usage, jboss5.x

We had the problem when the CPU util on a single core machine went to 100 %. The number of users is 8-10 on a server hosted at the ISP end. When the server was upgraded to 4 core, the same problem persists. We have used Hibernate and JSF for implementation and MySQL as the backend. I strongly feel it is a problem with the JBOSS configuration but unable to fix it. Kindly help

Comment: This question does not appear to be programming related. If it is, please reformulate it. Perhaps our sister site http://serverfault.com/ is the place to ask?

Comment: Most likely some part of your code is driving this load so high, you may want to get some profiling tool to help figure out what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that anyone is going to be able to help you on this without significantly information than you have provided ... and could reasonably provide in an SO question.

The best I can suggest is that you use [`jvisualvm`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) and [`jconsole`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jconsole.html) ... and the host operating system's system monitoring tools ... to try to get a handle on where your system's resources are being used.